# How to operate with float stored in dictionary in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

I have `NSDictionary *results`

When i do this:

```
self.tValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [results objectForKey:@"temperature"] + 273.15f];
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid operands for binary expression ('id _Nullable' and 'float')
```

Where I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "float" stored in the NSDictionary is likely to be an NSNumber (or possibly an NSString) - it can't actually be a "float". You therefore need to get the "floatValue" of your NSDictionary value, do your addition, and then use the "float" string format.

Try the following:

```
self.tValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [results[@"temperature"] floatValue] + 273.15f];
```

Answer (score 1):

you are adding float value with id object before doing that you must have convert `temperature` value into float Like:

```
  CGFloat temperature = [[results objectForKey:@"temperature"] floatValue];
  NSString *tValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", temperature + 273.15f];
```